# Variable data loss after exiting mongo db access Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm still a bit new to Node.js and Javascript. I know that javascript is asynchronous by nature, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem. I tried using Promises but that didn't help for this particular case (or maybe I don't know how promises work).

Inside my getChilds() function, I make a search by id in my mongo database and I push the found object to an array called childObjects that I receive by parameter in the getChilds() function.

The object is found and added to the childObjects array. I use console.logs to check that it works. The problem is that when we exit the function, the value for childObjects is undefined.

My getChilds() function:

```
function getChilds(id, childObjects, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Item.findById(id, function (err, item) {

            if (err) {
                console.log("There's no corresponding item for that id!");
                return (res.send(err));
            }
            console.log("CHILD ITEM:" + item);

            childObjects.push(item);

            console.log("chiild ojects: " + childObjects);
            // return childObjects;
            // res.send(childObjects);
            // return childObjects;
            // res.send(item);

            resolve(item);
            // childObjects.push(item);
        });
    });
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to explain how you are trying to call you `getChilds` function and what are childObjects before call, not even sure what you use `res` for

Comment: The childObjects is: var childObjects = new Array();       I actually don't use res for anything, I simply copied the structure of another function and forgot to delete the res. I could be left there if I eventually wanted to send a message to Postman, e.g. res.send("something");

Comment: It seems you need to push several items to `childObjects`. Please show the code that makes the necessary iteration to call `getChilds`: it will need to be part of the solution.

Comment: //IMPLEMENTATION
    var childObjects = new Array();
    var childs = [];
    childs = item.childs;
    console.log("!!!2312312CHILDS1231312312: " + item.childs);


    childs.forEach((id, index) => {
        console.log("This is the id:" + id); //outputs correctly the id in the terminal

       
        getChilds(id, childObjects, res);

    })

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass `childObjects` as argument, nor `res`. Instead collect the `item` into `childObjects` outside of the function:

```
function getChilds(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Item.findById(id, function (err, item) {
            return err ? reject(err) : resolve(item);
        });
    });
}
```

Use `Promise.all` to get your `childObjects` array:

```
// Somehow you will get an array of id values, maybe like this:
const childs = item.childs;
// Create promises for each of them
const promises = childs.map(getChilds);
// Promise.all will await all the promises to resolve, putting all items in an array: 
Promise.all(promises).then(childObjects => {
    console.log(childObjects);
    res.send(childObjects);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error occurred', err);
    res.send(err);
});
```

Note that the plural of "child" is "children" not "childs" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass `childObjects` in. 
You have two options: either you define `childObjects` at the same level of `getChilds`. So for instance if you can call `this.getChilds` then the `childObjects` array should exist at `this.childObjects`. Or you `resolve(item)` and in the callback of the function, where you did `this.getChilds(id).then(`, you push to the `childObjects` living in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You are totally right. 
You are facing two this problem because you used Promise. With Promise, Your code becomes to Non-Blocking code.

I can suggest two solutions to solve this issue.

> Scope:

```
let childObjects;
function getChilds(id, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ...
    });
}
```

> Return the value:

```
function getChilds(id, childObjects, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ...
            resolve({item: item, childObjects: childObjects);
        });
    });
}
```